# Compiling forms in C#

Tags: c#, forms, dll

I want to compile each individual form on my application to be used sort of as a dll on its own... I looked into this and found very confusing representations of assemblies, which may or may not be what I wanted.

Is it possible to compile the `form1.cs`, `form1.designer.cs` and `form1.resx` to be 1 single file which then will be able to be used as a dll. I use "dll" as an example because that is the functionality I need with each of these forms when compiled to a single file, I need to be able to call it and use it from a shell application.

I know it is possible in VS to create a separate project which will compile into a dll but with something on the verge of 80 forms to compile... it will be a messy thing to maintain. So basically, is there an easier way?

this is the closest code I could get, but it is in console, so it will be impractical if there are easier ways... also I am not sure if it will actualy compile `form1.cs`, `form1.designer.cs` and `form1.resx` and still work as a dll

```
csc /target:library /out:MathLibrary.DLL Add.cs Mult.cs
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: How does an 80-form-project get any less messy when you compile them on the command line one by one? Maybe you can find a pattern or hierarchy that you don't need 80 different forms from the start?

Comment: Let me make sure I understand this correctly: You want to produce 80 different `.dll`-files that you can then refer to and use in a separete application, right?

Comment: unfortunately, due to the unique initial design of the application... this is how it is, and this is how it will stay.. every form does a different thing, it is a fairly complex application... the idea behind the dll for each form is to make it easier to update when changes are needed

Comment: @Kjartan essentially.. yes.. I realise this may not be ideal but I have little say over this matter. Dont worry about the number, is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible? Yes. Advisable? Umm, not sure.

You must study the CSC options to use it in such a massive way.

Partial classes are simply each listed among the sources. [See here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/marcelolr/archive/2009/04/10/using-partial-classes-for-cleaner-more-maintainable-code.aspx)

The RESX file must be compiled by ResGen.exe to a resources file [see here](http://www.ehow.com/how_12189296_embed-resx-csc-compiler.html)

You will use the /References parameter to include other DLLs.

The real challenge will probably come when you try to get cross references to work, depending on the layout of your application. Is there a main hub that will control all forms? Is it a plug-in architecture?

Good luck

Comment: this looks like what I was looking at, thanks for the help with resx files too

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you are working with solution. It can contain multiple projects. For each `dll`, you must have one project. So create 80 projects, add to each of them single form, edit it, add some logic.

Then there will be a main project, which produce `exe`. You can reference all `dll`s in that project, but better don't. If you do, updating any of `dll` will required recompiling that `exe` too. You can load them dynamically or use sort of plugin system (to enumerate `dll`s, understand their purpose, etc). Then you obtain `Type` from assembly (loaded `dll`), create instance (which will call constructor, which calls `InitializeComponents`, which loads form resources) and display form.

Regarding abstraction, you surely need something. To example, login window. You can create a generic form with some focus, user interface and user interaction logic. But it has to communicated with main project (which encapsulate encryption, password storage model, user rights, etc). One easy way to do this is to provide 2 interfaces:

```
interface ILoginImplementation
{
    public void SetInitialUserName(string name);
}

interface ILoginLogic
{
    public bool TryAuthenticate(string name, string password);
}
```

`Implementation` is what your form **must** implement and `Logic` is what main project implements and supply when instantiating login form.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is probably not ideal, but I still think your best bet is to use Visual Studio and create a separate project for each `.dll` to be created.

By right clicking the Solution node and selecting `Add > New Solution Folder`, you can at least organize your projects into a somewhat more orderly hierarchy. That alone might go a long way to make your project more manageable.

**PS:** If you haven't already, you should definitely try to create an interface, or a base class (or both!) that each of your `Form`-classes can derive from or implement. If you're able to abstract away and generalize some of the logic, it is quite likely to save you a lot of work down the road.

Comment: thanks, and yes I actually use an abstracted base usercontrol but in most cases  the logic cannot be generalized because it is unique to the form.